# swift 3, datePicker, unrecognized selector

Tags: swift3, uidatepicker, unrecognized-selector

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged(datePicker:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)     

}

func datePickerChanged(datePicker:UIDatePicker) {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short

    let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)

    dateLbl.text = strDate
}
```

[datePicker.ViewController dpc:]: **unrecognized selector** sent to instance 0x7ffd834078c0

This code doesn't work. What i'm doing wrong? Please help me.

Comment: Press ⇧⌘F and search for `dpc`

Comment: @vadian Found it > http://imgur.com/a/xqNZI 
And what should i do next to fix it?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the reason, it's a dead connection. Delete it. You could make `datePickerChanged` an `IBAction` and connect it to that.

Comment: @vadian, Oh great! now it works! Thanks for good advice!